# string array in spinner

Tags: android

i have an array which is populated in the spinner adapter.
now i wanna change the size of the array! is it possible?
help! 
thank u
`public void classpopulate() {
        if (PEP.getUser() == null) {
            return;
        }

```
    classdetails = masterDataManager.getClassSections(PEP.getUser()
            .getUsername(), getApplicationContext());
    spnrClass = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrClass);
    spnrSubject = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrSubject);
    classname = new String[classdetails.size() + 1];
    classname[0] = "SELECET CLASS";

    for (int i = 1; i < classdetails.size() + 1; i++) {

        classname[i] = classdetails.get(i - 1).getClass_name() + "  "
                + classdetails.get(i - 1).getSection_name().toString();

    }

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterClasses = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item_class,
            R.id.spinnerclasstxt, classname);
    spnrClass.setAdapter(adapterClasses);
    spnrClass.setSelection(0);

    spnrClass
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int pos, long arg3) {
                    // LinearLayout layoutSpinnersubj = (LinearLayout)
                    // findViewById(R.id.layout_spinner);
                    // RelativeLayout subject_Text
                    // =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutsubjecttext);
                    int selectedindex = pos;
                    if (selectedindex == 0) {
                        spnrSubject.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        spnrSubject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        selectedClass = classdetails.get(selectedindex - 1);

                        subjectpopulate(selectedClass);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }

            });
```

`

Comment: yes u can change the size of the array...but mention when u want to populate it in the spinner i.e on button click or on coming back from other activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ArrayAdapter` methods `clear`, `add`, `insert` and/or `remove` to manipulate the adapter's data.

EDIT: From your comments, it sounds like you are eventually going to need to write your own custom adapter (probably by extending `BaseAdapter`), particularly if you want to have disabled (separator) rows, etc. You will have much more control over what gets displayed and how it looks. Search the web for *"android custom list adapter"* to find lots of examples of how to write one. It's not too difficult.

Nevertheless, if you want to keep using an `ArrayAdapter`, here's an example of removing the first element of the list (it assumes that the adapter has been saved in a member field `adapter`):

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(0));
```

For more complicated changes (like loading a completely different set of data), you might do something like this:

```
String[] newData = . . .
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false); // temporarily turn off auto-notification
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(newData);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies and turns auto-notifications back on
```

It's good practice to suspend auto-notification when you are making several changes in sequence.

Comment: for example i have a string array with data "a" "b" "c" and i am populating it to the spinner. but the drop down should have only "b" "C". help!

Comment: my ultimate aim is to add title to the spinner! help !!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

In your activity get references from your layout file like,

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Then, make adapter for that

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,YOUR_STRING_ARRAY);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then make one **arrays.xml** it is contains your string array.

for example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="string_array">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an ArrayList in place of an array

```
ArrayList<String> classname = new ArrayList<String>;
classname.add("SELECET CLASS");

for (int i = 1; i < classdetails.size() + 1; i++) {

        classname[i].add(classdetails.get(i - 1).getClass_name() + "  "
                + classdetails.get(i - 1).getSection_name().toString());

    }

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterClasses = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item_class,
            R.id.spinnerclasstxt, classname);
    spnrClass.setAdapter(adapterClasses);
    spnrClass.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: for example i have an array with data "a" "b" "C" "D"

Comment: and i wanna display only "C" "D" in my spinner. help